# How does Twisted reactor work with trial-based unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, twisted, trial

I have written a TCP/UDP intercepting proxy using Twisted and I want to add some unit tests to it. I want to setup an echo protocol, then send some data through my proxy, then check the returned response.

However, it seems like even for a simple test using a socket (let aside my intercepting proxy) to connect to the echoer, the reactor desn't *seem* to be spawned after `setUp` - the test hangs forever. If I add a timeout to the socket then a timeout exception is raised. I even tried to connect with `ncat` to make sure is not the manually created socket to blame - the echoer is listening indeed but I receive no echoed data back to the `ncat` client.

The test code I use is the following

```py
import pytest
import socket
from twisted.trial import unittest
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol


class EchoTCP(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)


class EchoTCPFactory(protocol.Factory):
    protocol = EchoTCP


class TestTCP(unittest.TestCase):
    """Twisted has its own unittest class
    https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.2.0/core/howto/trial.html
    """
    def setUp(self):
        self.iface = "127.0.0.1"
        self.data = b"Hello, World!"
        
        # Setup twised echoer
        self.port = reactor.listenTCP(
            8080,
            EchoTCPFactory(),
            interface=self.iface
        )

    def tearDown(self):
        self.port.stopListening()

    def test_echo(self):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((self.iface, self.port.getHost().port))
        
        sent = sock.send(self.data)
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        sock.close()

        assert data == self.data
```

To run it I use the following command

```sh
PYTHONPATH="${PWD}" trial --reactor=default mymodule
```

The output is the following and stays like this until I kill the process

```
mymodule.test.test_network
  TestTCP
    test_echo ...
```

It seems like I'm missing something regarding how the reactor works. I've looked for similar examples but couldn't get it working.

How should I write the test to get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I *must* run the test methods as `Deffered`, using [inlineCallbacks](https://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/twisted-17.9.0/core/howto/defer-intro.html#inline-callbacks-using-yield), so they are called when the reactor is running. To test this behavior I've used the following snippet

```py
    from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
    # [...]

    def check_reactor(self):
        # time.sleep(100)
        return reactor.running

    @inlineCallbacks
    def test_reactor(self):
        reactor_running = yield threads.deferToThread(self.check_reactor)
        assert reactor_running == True
```

...which makes the test successfully complete

```sh
mymodule.test.test_network
  TestTCP
    test_reactor ...                                                       [OK]

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.007s

PASSED (successes=1)
```

If I enable the sleep(100) in the calledback method, and connect with `ncat` in that timespan, the data that I send to the listening port is indeed echoed back